# Labview- How can I plot a list of values one by one

Tags: charts, labview, waveform

How can I plot (on a waveform chart) a list of values one by one? I need the terminal to be double because I'm planning to use the Peak Detector PtByPt VI and that's the data type for the input data.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited based on the comment: Plotting values after each other can be done with an array. The easiest way is than to loop through the array and do the Peak Detector vi.

[image: VI Snippet]

Comment: That's not what I need, I need the values to create just one line and if I use a bundle then I wouldn't be able to use the Peak Detector PtByPt VI

Comment: Thank you so much that's exactly what I was trying to do